# pairs trading or long short strategy given volatility of the stocks

Tags: cointegration, pairs-trading, longshort

Suppose I have 2 stocks and the only thing I know about them is their volatility and that they cointegrate. Let's say vol of stock A is 25% and B is 20%. Will I be able to find a hedge ratio only using the vol of 2 stocks? Assume that they track each other very closely and so mean reversion isn't an issue.

Comment: If your hedge ratio is your least squares beta you would need the covariance to estimate it.

Comment: Correlation would also help. For a minimum variance hedge ratio, $$h= \rho \sigma_A / \sigma_B$$.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation#Pearson.27s_product-moment_coefficient